# Changes in grub.cfg custom Ubuntu 22.04 ISO not present on boot

Tags: linux, grub2, boot-loader

I'm trying to follow instructions on how to make [autoinstall Ubuntu ISO](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall-iso/), but however I modify `linux` line in `grub.cfg` configuration file during customization of Ubuntu Server 22.04 ISO, modifications get lost.

I've tried to modify original menu entry:

```
menuentry "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

by setting it to:

```
menuentry "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/ ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

and then repack ISO. I do it with `livefs-edit` which produces new ISO image. If I mount that image, I can see that the change is really there, so `livefs-edit` does what it's supposed to.

However, when I boot virtual box VM using that image, that menu entry looks way different, with a bunch of other parameters, but with mine missing.

```
setparams 'Try or Install Ubuntu Server' 
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz auto=true preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg priority=critical quiet splash noprompt noshell automatic-ubiquity ... ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
```

It's interesting that If I add new menu entry to `grub.cfg`, I see that menu entry during boot, but `linux` parameters look the same as above, regardless of what I set.

So, it looks like there's a process which runs during ISO packing, which takes `grub.cfg` as input, and produces artifact which is actually used during boot (or this may happen in very early stage of booting). Anyway, my parameters are gone whatever is happening here.

Is there any way I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar, but targeting VMWare Fusion VMs hosted on M1 Macs. While trying to solve my problem, I may have stumbled on a solution to yours.

I could not get livefs-edit to work because it depends on 'losetup', which isn't available on macOS.  Anyhow, that blocker took me down a rabbit hole of remastering bootable ISOs.  Assuming your familiar with all the other steps of extracting ISOs, creating your cloud-init data, and revising your grub config, xorriso will take livefs-edit out of the mix and yield a bootable ISO with your autoinstall menu entry.

```
xorriso -as mkisofs \
--modification-date='2021101314195100' \
--grub2-mbr \
--interval:local_fs:0s-15s:zero_mbrpt,zero_gpt:"${ORIGINAL_ISO_PATH}" \
--protective-msdos-label \
-partition_cyl_align off \
-partition_offset 16 \
--mbr-force-bootable \
-append_partition 2 28732ac11ff8d211ba4b00a0c93ec93b \
--interval:local_fs:2470124d-2478587d::"${ORIGINAL_ISO_PATH}" \
-part_like_isohybrid \
-iso_mbr_part_type a2a0d0ebe5b9334487c068b6b72699c7 \
-c '/boot.catalog' \
-b '/boot/grub/i386-pc/eltorito.img' \
-no-emul-boot \
-boot-load-size 4 \
-boot-info-table \
--grub2-boot-info \
-eltorito-alt-boot -e \
'--interval:appended_partition_2_start_617531s_size_8464d:all::' \
-no-emul-boot \
-boot-load-size 8464 \
-isohybrid-gpt-basdat \
-o ubuntu-autoinstall.iso \
-V 'Ubuntu autoinstall' ${EXTRACTED_ISO_PATH}
```

Hopefully that solves it for you. For me, I think there is something I don't understand yet around boot partitions or boot images.  For *arm64.iso, there is no eltorito.img in them, so I think these two lines are near the root of my problem.

```
-c '/boot.catalog' \
-b '/boot/grub/i386-pc/eltorito.img' \
```